# How do I place a selection of many objects onto an arc in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have 3 objects that are 3 stars, I have them placed in a straight line.

I would like to know if there is a way to place them making an arc (like the paramount logo style). And if in this process the stars will rotate over themselves or can stay straight up.

I'm asking this question specifically for a selection of more than one object.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8820/multiple-images-spread-out-inside-circle-using-illustrator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many options exist.

1. If the arc has only 3 members, just lay the starts out in a straight line and move the middle one up. (3 points will always form an arc, as well as a triangle)
2. Another straight forward one is to draw an circle split it into a arc then snap the centers on of your star on that arcs points (you do have points napping enabled right)
3. Then there is the (almost universally forgotten by beginners) *rotate tool* and *transform again* (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>). Just move the rotate pivot.
4. Use a scatter brush of a star, on a manually drawn arc. (this has the benefit of being able to change number of stars later)
5. Instead of a scatter brush use a art brush.
6. Draw a star, and a invisible box. Then use the transfom effect on the corner of the group to rotate copies.  (this has the benefit of being able to change number of stars later)
7. Write a script
8. Manually write the strar formation postscript inside a EPS file then link the EPS.  (this has the benefit of being able to change number of stars later)

Do you need more? I'm sure i can come up with a few more if i put my head to it.

Comment: I had no idea there was scripts for illustrator. I was expecting a tool like a option box to control the curve of the arc and other settings. This will do it.

Comment: @Germán For a application to be useful in a wide context (read makes profit) then it has to have somewhat general tools. How many times do you actually draw an arc of stars? (answeer for me is i have never needed to do this until now). Also when you do you get a template, you can allways save documents and open them later. So if you need this lot just save it and reuse that file.  Anyway illustrator is at hart a direct modeler so if you are looking for advanced indirect features then illustrator is not for you.